# Strong Parameters and Nested Parameters - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting an error when sending a post request to my comments controller using **form_for([@post, @comment])**. To create a comment.

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CommentsController#create
```

Line causing the error:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

I know that it is down to a strong parameters issue but I can't seem to get it right. At the moment my model for posts is:

posts.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And for comments:

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

My current strong parameters setup for the comments controller is:

comments_controller.rb

```
  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:post).permit(comment: [:name, :body])
    end
```

And finally parameters as being reported by the error message are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"MSX1PrrvfzYBr/DNYaMgSw3opWmaJs82xd11JfLPIqI=",
 "comment"=>{"name"=>"",
 "body"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Comment",
 "post_id"=>"1"}
```

Anyone got any ideas where my strong params setup is broken - any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you're requiring your post, not your comment. Maybe try:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
end
```

then do:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's appreciated. Are there any guides or docs you would recommend I read around nested parameters?

Comment: Sure, check out the github page here: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems...

One problem is that you aren't using your `comment_params` in the `build` method...

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

should be

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params[:comment])
```

But we have another issue in that your sent `params` actually is not `{post: {comment: 'stuff here'}}` like your `comment_params` method indicates.  It's actually `{comment: 'stuff here'}`

So you should change comment params:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
end
```

And then to build your comment:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
```